# Broadcast Reciever not working. Declared in manifest

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter

I have a BroadcastReciever and a Service. When a Internet connection established it has to start service that download some data.

My BroadcastReceiver

```
public class NetworkStateListener extends BroadcastReceiver
{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent)
    {
    Toast.makeText(c,"started",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    c.startService(new Intent(c,DataDownloader.class));

    // TODO: Implement this method
    }

 }
```

Here is some codes of Manifest...

```
<receiver android:name="com.Example.SGSN.worker.NetworkStateListener" 
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter android:priority="999">
            <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION"/>
            <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED"/>
            <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WifiManager.SUPLICANT_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION"/>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

and requested permissions...

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Not even a single action is got triggered. I dont know where I committed mistake.I have also searched for answers but my problem not solved.
 The BroadcastReceiver works when I register it in activity dynamically. I need it in background. Someone help please.

Comment: Why do you use that - `android:process=":channel"`?

Comment: I dont know what exactly, I saw it in a tutorial video.

Comment: You have a typo in receiver => reciever

Comment: Are you starting the service in the main activity?

Comment: No, In the BroadcastReceiver

Comment: Are you using an alarm manager?

Comment: No, using receiver for a download task when connection is available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove:

`android:process=":channel"`

**UPD**

Here code of manifest which is 100% working:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.andrey.test">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main2">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name=".MyReceiver"
            android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION" />
                <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
                <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WifiManager.SUPLICANT_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION" />
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: removed android:process =":channel " but no improvement in outcome:-(

Comment: I've run that code and it is working. Ill copy whole manifest.

Comment: But here it is not showing any Toast notification and the service is not running.

Comment: Check that `android:name="SOMETHING"` - referencing your broadcast receiver.

Comment: Checked the package name and the path..both are correct

Comment: Got it !! fourth action should be "android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"

Answer (score 1):

In the manifest, did you set the receiver tag inside the application tag?

Like:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <receiver android:name=".NetworkChangeReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

Comment: Yes, but here just copied the code lines which is important

Answer (score 1):

Try out an implementation like this:

Firstly your service which will listen for changes in internet connectivity:

```
public class SyncService extends Service {

public static Intent getStartIntent(Context context) {
    return new Intent(context, SyncService.class);
}


@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, final int startId) {
    Timber.i("Starting sync...");

    if (!NetworkUtil.isNetworkConnected(this)) {
        Timber.i("Sync canceled, connection not available");
        stopSelf(startId);
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    //Here you can define what you need to do when internet is available
    //Can download from internet and sync to local for example

    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    if (mSubscription != null) mSubscription.unsubscribe();
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

public static class SyncOnConnectionAvailable extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION)
                && NetworkUtil.isNetworkConnected(context)) {
            Timber.i("Connection is now available, triggering sync...");
            context.startService(getStartIntent(context));
        }
    }
}
```

The broadcast receiver will start the service and then act according to what you have dictated in it's onStartCommand();

Next declare the service in the manifest as follows:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<service android:name=".SyncService"/>

<receiver
    android:name=".SyncService$SyncOnConnectionAvailable"
    android:enabled="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

This will inform the service anytime it detects a network change.

Now you need to start the service from any activity which I have no doubt would be your main activity since you want the service to run in the background. This example will only trigger when the main activity is started as per my example. You can tweak this to your liking.

The main activity:

```
public class MainActivity {

    public static Intent getStartIntent(Context context) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        return intent;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //this is where you start the service and it will start listening for connectivity changes 
        if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra(EXTRA_TRIGGER_SYNC_FLAG, true)) {
            startService(SyncService.getStartIntent(this));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

And this is just a NetworkUtil class that could come in handy:

```
public class NetworkUtil {

    public static boolean isNetworkConnected(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager cm =
            (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
    }

}
```

The service will be triggered from those two lines in the MainActivity onCreate(). Tweak this example to your needs. I have used parts of this example from ribot boilerplate code example found at https://github.com/ribot/android-boilerplate/.

Answer (score 0):

As of Android Nougat(API 24). Broadcast receivers declared in the Manifest will no longer be alerted of the "android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" event. Helps save battery :). Older versions of Android are not affected.

To listen to this event in Nougat, you have to register the broadcast programmatically.